# why png files are not loading into recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, png, picasso

I am currently working at a Android project, where I have to upload png files into Firebase Realtime-database. My app is retrieving images but when I used png files it's loading only five png files, I don't know what happened to the other png files.
When I make an edit with the image url one of the another image turn not working and the one I edited started to work.
I am using Picasso library to view the images...
Does anybody else encountered the same error...
I should complete the project as soon as possible 
Should this problem solves if I use glide instead of picasso???
myadapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private DatabaseReference reference;

    static Context context;
    static ArrayList<Profile> profiles;

    public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Profile> p) {
        context = c;
        profiles = p;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false));
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(profiles.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.desc.setText(profiles.get(position).getDesc());
        Picasso.get().load(profiles.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.image);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return profiles.size();
    }

    static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView title, desc;
        ImageView image;
        Button btn;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Main2Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("URL", profiles.get(getAdapterPosition()).getImage());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }


    }
}
```

mainactivity.java

```
public class helmet extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseReference reference;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<Profile> list;
    public MyAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_helmet);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclle);
        int numberOfColumns = 3;
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.HORIZONTAL));

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns));
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("helmet");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                list = new ArrayList<Profile>();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Profile p = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Profile.class);
                    list.add(p);
                }
                adapter = new MyAdapter(helmet.this, list);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(helmet.this, "Opsss.... Something is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
    }
```

....

Comment: Without code it difficult to say.

Comment: edited the quetion with my code